# NSPredicate returns different results on a fecthRequest vs filtering an array

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I have a Core Data SQLite type store, one of the attributes in my entity called Article is a string attribute called markAsArchived.

What I would like to do is setup a fetch request to get the first 100 items whose markAsArchived is not YES (string value, not bool).

So, here's the code I use to setup the fetch request, which returns 0 results.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Article"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markAsArchived != 'YES'"]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:100];
NSError *error = nil;
self.articles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];

if (error) {
    //Handle the error
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

However, if I take that exact same predicate, remove it from the fetch request, but instead use it to filter the array returned by the fetch request, I get some what desired results. Here is the code I use to do this.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Article"];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:100];
NSError *error = nil;
self.articles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]];

if (error) {
    //Handle the error
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
self.articles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.articles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markAsArchived != 'YES'"]]];
```

Now, my problem is that since I'm filtering the array of a 100 fetched items, the resulting filtered array usually ends up being less than 100 which is not what I want.

My guess is I'm doing something incredibly noobish when setting up the fetch request with the predicate. Any pointers as to what I might be doing wrong?

**PS:** Changing markAsArchived to a bool attribute instead of a string attribute is not an option.

**Update:** I have looked through the following questions, none of which seemed to have helped me.

[NSPredicate Returns No Results with Fetch Request, Works with Array Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405897/nspredicate-returns-no-results-with-fetch-request-works-with-array-filtering)

[Predicate works for array but not for fetchRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107452/predicate-works-for-array-but-not-for-fetchrequest)

**Update (March 1, 2013):*** As far as I can tell, the executeFetchRequest returns an empty array, not nil. I double checked to be sure.

Here is the debug output I get with the launch argument...

```
2013-03-01 20:29:48.218 PROJECTNAME[753:907] CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCONTENT, t0.ZDATE, t0.ZENCLOSURELENGHT, t0.ZENCLOSURETYPE, t0.ZENCLOSUREURL, t0.ZFULLTEXT, t0.ZIDENTIFIER, t0.ZIMAGE, t0.ZLINK, t0.ZMARKASARCHIVED, t0.ZREAD, t0.ZREADPOSITION, t0.ZSUMMARY, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZUPDATED, t0.ZFEED FROM ZARTICLE t0 WHERE  t0.ZMARKASARCHIVED <> ? ORDER BY t0.ZDATE DESC LIMIT 119
2013-03-01 20:29:48.221 PROJECTNAME[753:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = "YES"
2013-03-01 20:29:48.287 PROJECTNAME[753:907] CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0689s
2013-03-01 20:29:48.289 PROJECTNAME[753:907] CoreData: annotation: fetch using NSSQLiteStatement <0x1f218d70> on entity 'Article' with sql text 'SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZCONTENT, t0.ZDATE, t0.ZENCLOSURELENGHT, t0.ZENCLOSURETYPE, t0.ZENCLOSUREURL, t0.ZFULLTEXT, t0.ZIDENTIFIER, t0.ZIMAGE, t0.ZLINK, t0.ZMARKASARCHIVED, t0.ZREAD, t0.ZREADPOSITION, t0.ZSUMMARY, t0.ZTITLE, t0.ZUPDATED, t0.ZFEED FROM ZARTICLE t0 WHERE  t0.ZMARKASARCHIVED <> ? ORDER BY t0.ZDATE DESC LIMIT 119' returned 0 rows with values: ( )
2013-03-01 20:29:48.291 PROJECTNAME[753:907] CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0734s for 0 rows.
```

Comment: I assume you have done the obvious: double-checked all property names (upper/lowercase) and re-generated the NSManagedObject subclasses?

Comment: @MartinR : Affirmative. In fact, that's all I've been doing over and over again for days now. :-(

Comment: Can you check the return value of `[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]` ? Does `executeFetchRequest` return an empty array or `nil`? (`arrayWithArray` would return an empty array in both cases, so you have to check the actual return value!)

Comment: Another suggestion: Set the launch argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug = 3` and show us the debug output that is created for the `executeFetch` call.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this strange problem?

Comment: @MartinR No, unfortunately, because of time constraints, I had to start my refactoring efforts. Which is what has been consuming the majority of this week for me. I do still intend to get back to this issue, sometime this weekend hopefully. I really am sorry for not being able to do this sooner. Thanks so much for trying to follow up! :-)

Comment: I was just curious because there was a similar issue in the comments/chat following this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15026779/1187415, which also remained unsolved as I understand it.

Comment: @MartinR: executeFetchRequest seems to be returning an empty array, not nil. Also, I've updated my question with the debug output I get with the launch argument.

Comment: You could try to execute the SELECT statement directly on the database with the `sqlite3` command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the attribute `markedAsArchived` to be a string (which you will agree is bad design), the correct predicate for the fetch request is:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markedAsArchived != %@", @"YES"]
```

It is not safe to substitute constants as literals in the predicate format string. The above is the standard way to check for this attribute.

Comment: I'm working with somebody else's code here, and agreed, the design is pretty rough. markedAsArchived can be more than just YES or NO. Unfortunately, != or <> predicates don't seem to be doing the job at all. I've tried setting up the predicate with the format you provided here and a bunch of others too. The only thing that seems to be getting desired results is setting up a compound predicate with a whole bunch of == predicates to look for all other possibilities besides YES.

Comment: @SamJ.: So "==" works correctly but "!=" does not? What about `"NOT (markedAsArchived == 'YES')"` ?

Comment: @MartinR : Yes, "==" works correctly but "!=" & "<>" do not. And, no, "NOT (markAsArchived == 'YES')" doesn't seem to be working either. I still have a lot to learn about core data, so I think I should also ask, does it matter, that markAsArchived can also be nil, apart from all the different possibilities?

Comment: You can also compare to nil with `predicateWithFormat:@"attr = NIL"];`  . Also, if you are working with someone else's code, there is no reason not to refactor.

Comment: @Mundi : Yes, that is a part of my compound predicate. And, yes, refactoring is probably my best bet. But, the whole point of this question is to figure out if this can be made to work with a simple predicate, and why `!=` predicates aren't working while `==` predicates are. Trying to find the cause of the problem, instead of trying to dodge it entirely. Telling me that it's bad design & that I should refactor (both of which I agree with btw.) does not accomplish that.

Comment: Well maybe you should examine the physical contents of the database. Also, make sure your Entity classes are set up correctly (subclasses of managed object, correct attribute declarations etc.). Inequality with strings should definitely work. Also - check capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on the same issue ... in my case it was related to building the predicate string. You need to be careful if you use quotes or not. In your code I see:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markAsArchived != 'YES'"];
```

but it may actually need to be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"markAsArchived != YES"];
```

I had the same issue is NSNumber being wrapped in quotes.

Harry